# Tkinter update main frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

is there any way how to force to update main frame? I just need this:

```
if(saved(0)):
    Tk.Button(self.frame, text="Continue", command=self.pokracovat, relief="groove").grid()
```

First, I open main window. Function "saved" returns false, so button is not created. Then i open some another window using toplevel. Main window is vanished. Then I close that window and open main window - function "saved" now returns true, but still button doesnt appear. I use self.root.update(), but it doesnt work.

Comment: Just as an alternate idea would you be against setting the button "state" to tk.disabled when saved option not set thus making the button appear but in a DISABLED state unless the saved(0) option was set?

Comment: It is likely that this `if` statement is only being evaluated once. You should put a print statement in it to see when it is being called.

Comment: Problem is that function saved is still returning False. If i close window and start program again, then it returns True.

Comment: @ebarr Function is evaluted only when window is created. I use this: [link](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/26/tkinter-how-to-show-hide-a-window/)

Comment: There is not enough information for us to help you. We would need to see more code. If `saved(0)` returns True and the above code is executed, the button absolutely will be added to `self.frame`. There's much more to the problem than what you are showing us.

Comment: I looked at the link you sent, but I can't see your code on that page. Please post your code (or at least the amount of code necessary to recreate your problem) in the question.

Comment: @BryanOakley So I uploaded code here: [code](http://codeshare.io/hNrrK)

Answer (score -1):

To create a button when saved changes to True you can do the following:

1. You can use a loop that checks for the value and when the value changes then the loop does something. [tkinter loop and serial write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532523/tkinter-loop-and-serial-write)
2. you know where the value is changed and at this positions you insert some code that does what you want.
   For this the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) can be interesing.