# Python : Timer without blocking the window in Tkinter

Tags: python, timer, tkinter, window

For a project I need to do, I code a Bomberman.
I'm working with the software Pyzo, in Python language, and with Tkinter.
The problem I have is that I need to a timer for the bomb, for example, I put a bomb and it exploded 3 seconds after. 
But I have tested with many different things like .after; time module (time.sleep), a loop.
The consequence is always the same, the windows freezes and I can't move anymore, but when the loop is finished, the screen is refreshed and players are at new positions.

How can I do a proper timer to permit my bombs to explode after 3 seconds ?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post a code sample using the `after` method? That's probably going to be your best option, but it's hard to say where it went wrong without seeing it.

Comment: Can you post some code. It sounds like you are using the `after` method incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
widget.after(milliseconds, function, *arguments)
```

to let the `function(*arguments)` be called after milliseconds. If the function takes no arguments use `widget.after(milliseconds, function)`. One argument `widget.after(milliseconds, function, arg1)`, ....

`widget` can be `Tk()`, `Canvas()`, `Frame()`, `Label()`, ... object.

If you are interested in loops: [tkinter loop and serial write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532523/tkinter-loop-and-serial-write/21533765#21533765)